# Bulk Merge of CSV Files in PowerShell using parent folder name

Tags: powershell, csv

After beginning this task at the command line I realised I need to get down and dirty with Powershell. I have about 100 folders and each folder has a few thousand CSV files that I would like to merge together inside each folder. Ideally the merged CSV file(s) in each folder would use the parent folders name. For example, here is a top level folder conatining the 100 folders

E:\CSVFolders

The subfolders are named in a semi-random fashion like this:

E:\CSVFolders\Folder1
E:\CSVFolders\Folder18

So far I am at this point:

```
# Merge csv files and use the parent folder name
Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem File*.csv) |
    Export-Csv $folderName.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I am struggling to make the script enumerate the subfolders and then use their name as the basis for the merged CSV file so if anyone is able to shed light on this I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use two loops:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\CSVFolders' | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
    $csv = Join-Path $_.FullName ($_.Name + '.csv')
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter File*.csv | ForEach-Object {
        Import-Csv $_.FullName
    } | Export-Csv $csv -NoType -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Ansgar - as it stands that script dumps empty CSF files (with the folder names) at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

you can group by directory like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -Filter "*.csv" -Recurse | 
    group DirectoryName | 
        %{$dir=$_.Name; $_.Group.FullName | %{import-csv -path $_} | export-csv "$dir\global.csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

short version (for no purist) :

```
gci "c:\temp" -file -Filter "*.csv" -Rec | 
    group DirectoryName | 
        %{$dir=$_.Name; $_.Group.FullName | %{ipcsv -path $_} | epcsv "$dir\global.csv" -NoType}
```